# Is to possible to use session arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, session, push

The following code always echos Not present. Can you please give me the solution?

```
  <?php

      session_start();
      $_SESSION[$ses_arr]=array();
      $word="cat";
      array_push($_SESSION[$ses_arr],$word);

      if(in_array($word,$_SESSION[$ses_arr]))
        {
         echo "present";
        }
      else
        {
         echo "Not Present";
        }

   ?>
```

Comment: `$ses_arr` probably should be `ses_arr`?

Comment: If you are not seeing errors, [turn on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

this is vardump of your session array: [""]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" }

As you can see, because you haven't defined $ses_arr, its value is "" so "cat" is stored in $_SESSION[''][0]

Comment: Yeah, and also it's noteworthy in the following additional listing: `var_dump($ses_arr); reset($_SESSION); var_dump(key($_SESSION));` shows, that "Undefined variable: ses_arr" was converted from `NULL` to `string(0) ""`

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `$_SESSION['ses_arr']` if `'ses_arr'` is an index.

2) Use `$_SESSION[ses_arr]` if `ses_arr` is a predefined constant.

```
define('ses_arr','mySessionArray');
```

3) Use `$_SESSION[$ses_arr]` if `$ses_arr` is a predefined variable.

```
$ses_arr = 'mySessionArray';
```

---

The following code will work for you:

```
  <?php

  session_start();
  $_SESSION['ses_arr']=array();
  $word="cat";
  array_push($_SESSION['ses_arr'],$word);

  if(in_array($word,$_SESSION['ses_arr']))
    {
     echo "present";
    }
  else
    {
     echo "Not Present";
    }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the `$ses_arr` variable.

Define it and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that `$ses_arr` is some identifier you have to decide which key you'll use to save your data in, or that you've mistaken a string for a variable.

First and foremost, turn on errors by placing this at the top of your script right after `<?php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If you've mistaken the string for a variable it will show errors. In that case, replace `$sess_arr` with `'sess_arr'` and it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php

  session_start();
  $ses_arr = array();
  $_SESSION['ses_arr']=$ses_arr;
  $word="cat";
  array_push($_SESSION['ses_arr'],$word);

  if(in_array($word,$_SESSION['ses_arr']))
    {
     echo "present";
    }
  else
    {
     echo "Not Present";
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling PHP what the variable $ses_arr means.
After session_start(); try $ses_arr = "ses_arr"; then it should work.